# Multiple structs, same fields that need to be accessed in a method

Tags: c, struct, generic-programming

I currently try to write some lil literal console game for fun in C.

For that, i need to be able to print window-like structures in ... well ... C.

I want to use a generic rendering method (lets call it `frame_render(...)`) to render all different "ui elements"

The problem now is: how to solve this?

given the scenario:

```
// Theoretical base
struct frame { int x; int y; int width; int height; }
struct button { int x; int y; int width; int height; ... }
struct whatever { int x; int y; int width; int height; ... }
```

how could i ensure that my `x`, `y`, `width` and `height` are always in the correct spot memory wise?
is it enough to "just" put them in the same order at the very begining?

also, how to design the method header to accept it?

Comment: How do you pass the structs to the method? Via `void*`?

Comment: plan is to pass them into `frame_render(frame*)` more or less. They will be sitting in a single list that gets iterated via a for loop

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> is it enough to "just" put them in the same order at the very begining?

Yes, if you're careful as you've done above.

> also, how to design the method header to accept it?

There are different ways to do this.

Here's an example, using the [ugly] equivalent of a `c++` "base" class:

```
enum type {
    FRAME,
    BUTTON,
    WHATEVER
};

struct geo {
    int x;
    int y;
    int width;
    int height;
    enum type type;
};

struct frame {
    struct geo geo;
};

struct button {
    struct geo geo;
    int updown;
};

struct whatever {
    struct geo geo;
    int what;
    int ever;
};

void
frame_render(struct geo *geo)
{
    struct frame *frm;
    struct button *but;
    struct whatever *what;

    switch (geo->type) {
    case FRAME:
        frm = (struct frame *) geo;
        frame_render_frame(frm);
        break;

    case BUTTON:
        but = (struct button *) geo;
        printf("x=%d y=%d updown=%d\n",geo->x,geo->y,but->updown);
        frame_render_button(but);
        break;

    case WHATEVER:
        what = (struct whatever *) geo;
        printf("x=%d y=%d what=%d ever=%d\n",
            what->geo.x,what->geo.y,what->what,what->ever);
        frame_render_whatever(what);
        break;
    }
}
```

Here's a way to use a virtual function table:

```
enum type {
    FRAME,
    BUTTON,
    WHATEVER
};

struct geo;

// virtual function table
struct virtfnc {
    void (*calc)(struct geo *);
    void (*render)(struct geo *);
};

struct geo {
    int x;
    int y;
    int width;
    int height;
    enum type type;
    struct virtfnc *fnc;
};

struct frame {
    struct geo geo;
};

struct button {
    struct geo geo;
    int updown;
};

struct whatever {
    struct geo geo;
    int what;
    int ever;
};

void
frame_render(struct geo *geo)
{
    struct frame *frm = (struct frame *) geo;

    // whatever
}

void
button_render(struct geo *geo)
{
    struct button *but = (struct button *) geo;

    // whatever
}

void
whatever_render(struct geo *geo)
{
    struct whatever *what = (struct whatever *) geo;

    // whatever
}

void
any_render(struct geo *geo)
{

    geo->fnc->render(geo);
}
```

Here's a third way that uses a `union`. It is simpler but requires that the base struct be as large as the largest sub-class:

```
enum type {
    FRAME,
    BUTTON,
    WHATEVER
};

struct frame {
    ...
};

struct button {
    int updown;
};

struct whatever {
    int what;
    int ever;
};

struct geo {
    int x;
    int y;
    int width;
    int height;
    enum type type;
    union {
        struct frame frame;
        struct button button;
        struct whatever what;
    } data;
};

void
any_render(struct geo *geo)
{

    switch (geo->type) {
    case FRAME:
        render_frame(&geo->data.frame);
        break;

    case BUTTON:
        render_button(&geo->data.button);
        break;

    case WHATEVER:
        render_whatever(&geo->data.what);
        break;
    }
}
```

---

**UPDATE:**

> is this approach casting safe? eg. putting all into some array that is of the type `frame*` and then just accessing `frame->geo`? or would that cause any problems with later calls to `free(..)`?

No problem with `free` if allocations are done with the *derived* types (e.g. `frame`, `button`), but *not* the base type `geo`: `malloc(sizeof(struct button))`.

To have a *simple* array [of shapes], the `union` method would need to be used (i.e. all derived structs must have the same size). But, this would be wasteful if we had some subtype that used a *lot* more space than the others:

```
struct polyline {
    int num_points;
    int x[100];
    int y[100];
};
```

This *could* still be done with methods #1 or #2 [where the subtype structs are of different sizes] with an *indirect* pointer array:

```
void
all_render(struct geo **glist,int ngeo)
{

    for (;  ngeo > 0;  --ngeo, ++glist)
        any_render(*glist);
}
```

Rather than an array of different shapes, I'd consider a [doubly] linked list. This allows the subtype structs to have different sizes. We'd add a `struct geo *next` element to `struct geo`. Then, we could do:

```
void
all_render(struct geo *geo)
{

    for (;  geo != NULL;  geo = geo->next)
        any_render(geo);
}
```

The list approach may be preferable, particularly if we add/remove shapes on a dynamic basis [or reorder them based on Z-depth].

Or, some shapes might *contain* others. So, we could add `struct geo *children` to `struct geo`. Then, it's easy to (e.g.) draw a containing box, then all the shapes within that box by traversing the `children` list. If we go for `children`, we may as well add `struct parent *parent` as well so each shape knows what shape contains it.

Comment: is this approach casting safe? eg. putting all into some array that is of the type `frame*` and then just accessing `frame->geo`? or would that cause any problems with later calls to `free(..)`?`

Answer (score 5):

If all of the structures start with members of the same types, in the same order, corresponding members will have the same offsets.  Most compilers can be configured to allow a pointer of any structure type to be used to inspect members of the Common Initial Sequence of any other, but there are a few issues:

1. On some unusual platforms, if an object is followed by padding bytes, an instruction that writes the object and padding bytes together (likely storing meaningless values in the latter) may be faster than instructions that write only the object.  If a member is followed by a padding byte in some structures, but by meaningful data in another, a write to that member using the type where it's followed by padding bytes may write overwrite the "padding bytes" with meaningless values, thus corrupting the values of the following members in the other structure types.  I am unaware of any architectures in current use where this would be an issue for any struct members other than bitfields, and I am unaware of any current implementations where this would be an issue even for those, but such possibilities could arise on some platforms, especially with bitfields.
2. Given something like:

   ```
   int readField1OfS1(struct s1 *p) { return p->field1; }

   struct s2 *myStruct2Ptr;

   if (readField1ofS1((struct s1*)myStruct2Ptr)
      ...
   ```

   some compilers like gcc and clang won't reliably allow for the possibility that the value returned from the function might depend upon a value held by part of the Common Initial Sequence of an object of type `struct s2` at the time of the call unless optimizations are disabled (e.g. using the `-fno-strict-aliasing` option).  I would think that presence of a cast from `struct s2*` to `struct s1*` within the function call expression should allow a quality compiler to recognize that anything function might do something with an object of type `struct s1` might be done on a `struct s2`, but since the Standard doesn't explicitly require that, the authors of gcc and clang refuse to make any effort to reliably recognize such constructs even in straightforward cases like the above.

Code which makes use of the Common Initial Sequence rule will work reliably on nearly any suitably-configured compiler, but some like **gcc and clang must be specially configured using `-fno-strict-aliasing` option**.  The ability to exploit Common Initial Sequence guarantees has been a well-established part of the language since 1974, and when the Standard was written, anyone familiar with the language would have understood that it was designed to allow for constructs like those above, which compilers should have no difficulty recognizing.  Since the authors of the Standard failed to explicitly require that the CIS guarantees be honored in useful fashion, however, the authors of clang and gcc have decided they'd rather claim that programs relying upon the decades-old CIS guarantees is "broken" than honor 40+ years of precedent.

Comment: I am not fully sure if that is a "yes it works" or a "yes it works, as long as you do not use clang/gcc without a special flag".

Comment: @X39: I think it's clear that the authors of the Standard intended it to work, and in practice it will work as long as you make certain to use an appropriate flag on compilers that require it.  The only two compilers I know of that require such a flag to make use of the CIS guarantees are clang and gcc, but it's possible that there are others.  Note that clang and gcc definitely do *not* support such code without the flag.

Comment: so basically, i must fall back to pretty much what has been posted by others if i want to stay safe and clear? As far as my understanding goes from googling quickly, `fno-strict-aliasing` would disable optimization on some occasions

Comment: @x39: Write the code how it makes sense and document what is required to make it work.  The Standard makes no attempt to fully specify a language that is useful for any particular purpose, and the dialect processed by clang and gcc with maximum optimizations enabled might be great for a few specialized purposes that don't involve processing input from unknown sources, but really isn't suitable for most others.  Rather than bending over backward to write code in an unsuitable dialect, make use of "popular extensions" when appropriate--just document that you're doing so.

Comment: I very much thank you @supercat for literally expanding my knowledge on that topic. But i accepted *Craig Estey* simply due to his answer containing the approach that i will now use.

Comment: @X39: BTW, a detail I forgot to mention: learn about the `restrict` qualifier, and use it when appropriate.  Proper use of that qualifier can re-enable most of the useful optimizations blocked by `-fno-strict-aliasing`, and many more besides.  I find it bizarre that compilers didn't get really aggressive with type-access rules until after `restrict` rendered them largely unnecessary.

Comment: I can see your first point being an issue on an architecture that is word addressable. Writing to a `char` might require a read-modify-write which could be optimised to a write if the compiler thought it was all that was at that address. Very good answer though, nice background on CIS.

Comment: @X39: The approach of prefixing everything with a "base type" can work in some cases, but depending upon object sizes and alignments it may end up requiring that many structures include otherwise-unnecessary padding.  Such an approach may also run afoul of future notions of "pointer provenance" which are being explored for inclusion into the Standard.  Given `struct foo {struct bar b; int q; ...} f;` a compiler would benefit from knowing whether a call to `doSomething(&f.b);` might affect `f.q`, and I think the people pushing pointer provenance would like to allow compilers to assume it won't.

Comment: @X39: If a programmer writes `doSomething((struct s1*)struct2Ptr);` a compiler which pays any attention to such things will have all of the information necessary to recognize that the recipient of the pointer might process it as a `struct s1` or a `struct s2`.  If a programmer writes `doSomething(&struct2Ptr->header);` a compiler would have no information about whether `doSomething` will limit its actions to just the header, or might access all of .  I believe in giving compilers the information they need to optimize safely and effectively, and passing just the header pointer doesn't.

Comment: @X39: Another advantage of the Common Initial Sequence approach is that on implementations that support it, a function that expects `struct polygon { int count; struct vertex points[];};` can be passed a static or automatic duration object of type `struct triangle { int count; struct vertex points[3];};`, or `struct pentagon { int count; struct vertex points[5];};`, etc. provided that `count` is set to 3 or 5, respectively.  The header-struct approach won't support such variadic types that aren't allocated on the heap.

Answer (score 2):

The "classical" method is to have a `struct` that contains a `union` of all possible objects and an `enum` that identifies which exactly object has been passed:

```
struct renderable {
    enum {FRAME, BUTTON, WHATVERE, ...} type;
    union {
        struct frame frame;
        struct button button;
        struct whatever whatever;
        ....
    } data;
};
```

After passing this struct to the renderer, use a `switch` on the `type` field to extract the coordinates, etc:

```
void renderer (renderable *obj, ...) {
    ...
    switch(obj->type) {
        case FRAME: x = obj->data.frame.x; ...; break;
        case BUTTON: x = obj->data.button.x; ...; break;
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

It was reportedly this kind of monstrosity that encouraged Stroustrup to invent C++ :)

**Edited**

Another "classical" solution is to have a separate `struct` that has the dimensions and the position of any object:

```
struct geometry {
    int x, y, width, height;
}
```

You can store this structure at the beginning of any object-specific `struct` and use a cast to gain access to it:

```
struct frame {
    struct geometry geo;
    // more stuff
};

struct frame frame = {....};
rendered((void*)&frame, ...);
```

In the renderer:

```
void renderer (void *obj, ...) {
    ...
    struct geometry *geo = (struct geometry *)obj;
    geo->x ...
}
```

The latter approach may be somewhat unsafe. To make it 100% safe, separate the geometry from the object-specific information and pass them to the renderer as two separate structs.

Comment: I kinda like this approach, though ... it will require that all types are known in my `renderable` (or `frame`) struct

Comment: If you do not know all the types, how would you render them?

Comment: They are all rendered the same :) thats the actual fun part.. above scenario is only some broken down example though.. differences are minimal and mostly related to how they actually be used and not related to rendering at all

Comment: according to what was posted by *supercat*, this could be problematic on some compilers (eg. gcc). Think i will accept the answer of *Craig Estey* simply due to timing and "completeness". Have my appreciation though :)

Comment: The classical approach is actually to use pointers to whatever structure type is appropriate; a well-known example is the SOCK_ADDR class.The code I've seen from that era rarely uses unions for that purpose.  Unfortunately, when compiler writers asked the authors of the Standard whether compilers were required to uphold CIS guarantees even in cases where it would be useless, the authors of the Standard agreed that it was not necessary to have the Standard mandate it, figuring that people seeking to write quality compilers would uphold them in cases where they were useful whether or not...

Comment: ...the Standard required them to do so.  Support for common patterns of CIS access via pointers used to be a 100% universal extension among commonplace compilers, since it was obviously useful and cost nothing.  Unfortunately, the authors of the Standard neglected to have Standard itself explicitly say that it makes no attempt to mandate all of the behaviors necessary to make any implementation suitable for any particular purposes.  The Rationale acknowledges the possibility of a low-quality implementation being useless but conforming, but the Standard itself doesn't.