# How to store any type in void* at runtime?

Tags: c, byte, dynamic-arrays

I'm writing a dynamic array in C:

```
struct array {
  int len;
  int cap;
  void *data;
};
```

It's easy to store values if I know the type:

```
void set(array* a, int idx, int val) {
    ((int*)a->data)[idx] = val;
}
```

But I want to accept any type (void*):

```
void set(array* a, int idx, void* val) {
    a->data[idx] = val;
}
```

This obviously doesn't compile because `'void' is not assignable`

As I understand, compiler needs information about the type to get its size and calculate the offset to access data.

Is there a way to do this on my own? Operate directly on bytes, something like

```
void set(array* a, int idx, void* val, int size) {
    *((char*)a->data + size * idx) = val;
}
```

Basically I want to make them similar to Go slices. You can read about their built in generic types here:

https://dave.cheney.net/2018/05/29/how-the-go-runtime-implements-maps-efficiently-without-generics

No templates, no unboxing. They use `void*` for data  storage.

Comment: Do you want an "array" of uniform types or can every element be of a different type?

Comment: See my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52788499/5382650 This provides a baseline and several variants, one of which may be to your liking.

Comment: @Swordfish, every element has the same type. I want to do it like in Go. Dynamic arrays without templates and unboxing.

Comment: Here's the second part: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52749660/5382650 You can use the various methods (e.g. `switch`, virtual function table, etc.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose a `memcpy` should do what you are looking for:

```
void set(array* a, int idx, void* val, int size) {
    memcpy(a->data + size * idx, val, size);
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I should have really thought of it. The source of the function was also useful to understand how pointers work in C: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/master/libgcc/memcpy.c

Answer (score 0):

first of all you need to use void* * data - to store an array, and not a single pointer to an element.

from what you have
[a->data = (void*)val; ]  should run fine.

it's only a pointer to the data, and it can be stored as void. you will need to know how to read the data when you will want to de-reference it.

if val points to an int- in order to read it you will have to cast it to let the compiler know how many bytes to read.
so :  *(int *)(a->data);

Comment: But then I'd have to do N mallocs for each void* in data, right?

Comment: if you get the length of the array: a->data = (void* *)calloc(_initSize,1);  for example when you create the array

Comment: to add a new element:                                    static void AddData( array* a, void* _item)
{
 *( a->data + a->curr_cap) = _item;
 ++(a->curr_cap);
}