# Generic Pointer dereferencing using a typedefined datatype

Tags: c, pointers, structure, void-pointers, dereference

My Code is like this below

```
typedef unsigned short  uint16;

struct STR
{
    const int x;
    const uint16 y;
    const int z;
    void* sptr;
};

struct STR s2[2] = 
{
    {1, 4, 6, {&s2[0].x, &s2[0].y, &s2[0].z}},
    {10,40, 60, {&s2[1].x, &s2[1].y, &s2[1].z}}
};

int main()
{
    void* tptr = s2[0].sptr;
    printf("%d %d %d", *((int*)tptr), *( (uint16*)tptr+1 ), *((int*)tptr+2));
    return 0;
}
```

Here I am using a void pointer because I will be deferencing different data type from the structure. Here the output I am expecting to get is

Expected Output: 1  4  6

But if I use

```
printf("%d %d %d", *((int*)tptr), *( (uint16*)tptr+1 ), *((int*)tptr+2));
```

I am getting output as  1  0  6. Here I have used a type-defined datatype uint16 for deferencing.

Instead if I use

```
printf("%d %d %d", *((int*)tptr), *( (int*)tptr+1 ), *((int*)tptr+2));
```

I am getting the correct output as 1  4  6. Why uint16 type is not able to dereference the pointer and getting 0 value. Please anyone do help and provide ideas for solving this issue.

Comment: You can't assign to a pointer (i.e. `sptr`) the way you are doing it. See Roflcopter4's answer for the reason(s) why. I think I understand what you're _ultimately_ trying to do. See my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52749660/5382650 for a different approach to achieve your goal.

Comment: Does that compile — does the initialization compile?

Comment: Yes it compiles. The problem facing is the accessing of the structure elements using the generic pointer as the structure has different data types of different sizes. Hence each data sits on different location in the matrix based on the individual data types of other elements in the structure. Thus this will vary if we add more elements in the structure or vary any data type of the existing element. We may derive some formula that can solve this. But seems bit impossible. Otherwise we should have an array of pointers, in that case each pointer points to each element of structure individually.

Comment: Casting `tptr` to `uint16 *` and adding 1, probably means you are reading the higher 2 bytes of x.  Write `*( (uint16*)tptr+2 )` and see what happens, although this is not usually how you would write **dereferencing**.

Comment: Why not use a union?

Answer (score 0):

There are a few problems that I see here. Firstly, you can't declare structures like that. A `void *` variable is a pointer. You are attempting to define a whole structure in its place, and using incorrect syntax to do that. I'm surprised the compiler didn't reject the code.

You'll obviously need to define a structure that accepts 3 integer pointers for values as well. If you really want to declare everything all in one go like that, and have the fourth element be a pointer, you can use a compound literal like this:

```
#pragma GCC diagnostic ignored "-Wmissing-braces"
struct other_struct {
        const int *x;
        const uint16 *y;
        const int *z;
};
struct STR s2[2] = {
    {1, 4, 6, (struct other_struct[1]){&s2[0].x, &s2[0].y, &s2[0].z}},
    {10,40, 60, (struct other_struct[1]){&s2[1].x, &s2[1].y, &s2[1].z}}
};
```

Please note that the compiler may reject a compound literal at file scope (I think MSCV does).

You also seem to have been a victim of padding here. The compiler will always attempt to align the data in a structure to a multiple of your machine's word size (8 bytes for 64-bit) unless you explicitly tell it not to. Furthermore, things are often lined up to at least a 4-byte boundary (the size of an integer). Because what you're doing is completely undefined behavior, your compiler simply attempted to extend the structure by giving each element the size of an integer. When you are trying to view the next int16 in your struct, you look ahead 2 bytes, but the next value is actually 4 bytes ahead, so you get a value of 0. That also explains why it works when you cast to `int *`.

EDIT: Actually I made a mistake above. Sorry. Your code wasn't working as expected not necessarily because of padding but because of how you wrote your **pointer arithmetic**. Trying to find the elements in the original array that way is really not possible, and certainly undefined behavior in any case.

Comment: compound literals are file scope are allowed

Comment: @M.M My mistake. MSVC rejects them as the initializer for a static variable. GCC and clang don't, although they give a warning. I just assumed that a restriction upon static variables would apply equally to global ones.

Comment: Initializers of static variables must be constant expressions; a compound literal is not a constant expression. (But its address is)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all for your comments. To solve this undefined behavior issue in the memory matrix of the structure. I replaced the void pointer in the structure to an array of pointers and accessing it with the help of dual pointer and now this works fine. But it can consume some more memory. New code as this

```
typedef unsigned short  uint16;

struct STR
{
    const int x;
    const uint16 y;
    const int z;
    void* sptr[3];
};

struct STR s2[2] = 
{
    {1, 4, 6, {&s2[0].x, &s2[0].y, &s2[0].z}},
    {10,40, 60, {&s2[1].x, &s2[1].y, &s2[1].z}}
};

int main()
{
    void** tptr = s2[0].sptr;
    printf("%d %d %d", *((int*)*tptr), *( (uint16*)*(tptr+1)), *((int*)*(tptr+2)));
    return 0;
}

//Output: 1  4  6
```